# Can't find variable in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a web APP (game).
I am trying to call a Game function out of "js/game" in my main html file. and somehow - it could not be linked as
console throw me an error.
Gives the "Can't find variable: Game"

I have played with "Game file" making it as class, exporting it, changing it.
Checked everything and still couldn't spot an error.

game.js :

````
``` let Game = function() {

    constructor(canvas, context) {
    // this.config = config; // customization
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.context = context;
```
````

Head Html:

```
<script src="js/game.js"></script>

<script>$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#high-scores-page").hide();
        $("#about-page").hide();
        $("#canvas").hide();
        $("#game-over-box").hide();

        $("#start-game-button").click(function () {
            $("#menu-page").hide();
            $("#game-over-box").hide();
            $("#canvas").show();

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var game = new Game(canvas, context);
            game.newGame();
            game.run();
        });
</script>
```

Expect it to work properly. Instead having:

> Can't find variable: Game

Comment: Why you need  an explicit constructor ,when your function already acts as a constructor??

Comment: Can you log out `Game` after the script import so you can see if you're not importing the script properly?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an explicit constructor in your Game object as your Game is already the constructor. Just remove the constructor and pass all the needed arguments to the Game constructor itself:

```
let Game = function (canvas, context) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.context = context;
}

Game.prototype.newGame = function () {
    //your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Make sense - but unfortunately still havin the "Uncaught ReferenceError: Game is not defined" error

Comment: @FrostyDog. I believe that you don't have any parenthesis around your let Game = ... anywhere in your game.js? And your Game declaration is still in the global context? Otherwise the **let** keyword scopes your Game variable to block-level context created by  parenthesis which makes the Game invisible outside. It would be helpful to look into your actual game.js file

Comment: If I understand right:
U are saying that let keyword scope Game var to block-level and makes it invisible from outside.
Which is totally make sense, since I have solved the problem by making it global var by assigning:
window.Game = Game in game.js

Answer (score 0):

Adding in **Game.js** after variable declaration block of code :

```
window.Game = Game
```

Fixes the problem. By this we are making Game variable global one.

**!! Note:** As I have read - this is not the best solution, but at least it makes everything working, since now the variable could be accessed.